# delete a bus in matpower

Tags: matlab, matpower

I am a beginner in matlab and Matpower. I have a load bus in system that has two branches. When I deleted these two branch power flow is not converged. How can I solve this problem? When I changed the type of bus to 4, it converged but the branches also connected to the bus. Is there are any option for that in matpower? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be easier for people to help you if you could share a bit more about your problem, perhaps some of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should isolate the bus first by deleting the two branches and then use matpower's `ext2int`.

From the [manual](https://matpower.org/docs/MATPOWER-manual-6.0b1.pdf):

> ext2int first removes all isolated buses,  off-line generators and
>   branches,  and any generators or branches connected to  isolated 
>   buses.   Then  the  buses  are  renumbered  consecutively,  beginning 
>   at  1